# Bash: excluding duplicate rows (both of each pair) based on one column

Tags: bash, duplicates

I have a file (called example.txt) that looks like the following:

```
A B C  
D E F  
H I C  
Z B Y  
A B C  
T E F  
W O F
```

Based on column 2 only, I wish to identify all rows which have a non-unique entry and remove them completely. My real file may have duplicates entries, triplicates entries, quadruple entries etc. I just want to keep the rows for which the entry of column 2 is unique.

The output file should look like this:

```
H I C  
W O F
```

I initially wanted to do this in R but my file is so big that R is too slow and is crashing. So I would like to do this in bash directly. I am new to bash, I tried this but it is not working:

```
arrayTmp=($(cat example.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -d))  
sed "/${arrayTmp[@]}\/d" example.txt
```

Comment: The only **duplicate** row is ABC, why don't you try to rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to rephrase it now. What I meant is that I want to identify all rows which have the same entry in column 2 and based on that, delete all those rows. I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order does not matter:

```
awk '{a[$2]=$0;b[$2]++}END{for (i in b){if(b[i]==1){print a[i]}}}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these characters only presence in 2nd column, this is achievable by selecting non-matching lines in example.txt, and no array required.

```
tmp=$(cat example.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -d)
grep -v -f <(echo -e "$tmp") example.txt
```

output:

```
H I C
W O F
```